# Help me solve this equation: $x^\frac23 - 9x^\frac13+8=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Not sure what to call this type of equation so please let me know. I'm having trouble solving it though.

Solve the equation:
$$x^\frac23 - 9x^\frac13+8=0$$

Comment: You could call it quadratic-like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try the substitution $y = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$. This should give you a quadratic.

Comment: oh wow easy! So cube root of 8 and 1 should be my solutions, correct?

Comment: Edit: you should get $x^{\frac{1}{3}} = 8$ or $1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: put $\,t:=x^{1/3}\,$ and get the easy quadratic

$$0=t^2-9t+8=(t-8)(t-1)\ldots\ldots$$